# FireFox version of tidy

Tags: firefox, tidy

I'm looking to create a binary that takes an html string on stdin, and spits out a well formed xml string representing the DOM. Basically "tidy" but using FireFox.

Any ideas where I should hook into the FF source code?

Comment: Why do you want Firefox to do the work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple rendering tests included in the source code. Some of them are "close" to what I'm looking for but the hooks have to be slightly modified. But as a starting point, the rendering tests are the best place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen `Firebug`'s HTML tab? Or the `Html Validator` plugin?

Comment: of course, but I don't want a GUI, just a command line program to tidy up HTML.